# ¿Como configurar o crear un token JWT personalizable con C#?

Tags: c#, jwt

he estado viendo en la documentacion de Microsoft en .NET como se genera un token pero este token se genera de forma local [CLIC AQUI LINK DOCUMENTACION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/jwt-authn?view=aspnetcore-8.0), yo quisiera saber donde puedo conseguir como personalizar o crear un token desde cero en C#, asi para poder tener mas manipulacion de los token que pueda generar, he visto que se genera con claims pero no entiendo el codigo, por que actualmente con la documentacio que poseo ahorita no me serviria porque si requiero crear una api donde los usuarios externos tengan acceso como se haria?

Comment: A que te refieres con un token personalizable?

Comment: me refiero crear un token JWT con c# no encuentro documentacion solo de otro programador pero no entiendo el codigo y cuando difo personalizable es que pueda crearlo desde cero o con una biblioteca a que me oriente a crear dicho token y yo darle mis partes tecnicas, espero que me de a entender.